# Grab data from some custom OpenStreetMap

Tags: parsing, openstreetmap

I need to once parse the data from some **custom** OpenStreetMap (with the locations of some specific gas stations), which looks like this:

[image: custom OSM]

Is it possible to get this data with some code or ready-made parser?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend http://overpass-turbo.eu/ where you can query OpenStreetMap data in a very flexible way.

Comment: Yes, this is a really powerful instrument, but it works only with the own OpenStreetMap data. What if I want to grab the data from someone's **custom** map?

Comment: Which kind of custom map?

Comment: For example, I want to integrate on my research website all the locations of 10,500 Walmart stores around the globe. Suppose they are available on the custom OpenStreetMap on the Walmart website. Of course, I can make it manually, one by one, but that's crazy time demanding.